# Running Apache Superset in systemd service file not working. Error: Could not locate a Flask application

Tags: systemd

New to creating bash script in Linux. I wanted to create a bash script for installing and setting up Apache Superset dashboard. I get it to install all the dependencies and requirements no problem whatsover. The problem now is I want to create a system service file for Apache Superset so that the service will run in background.
Running this command will only persist as long as I am connected to the instance via SSH:
`superset run -h 0.0.0.0 -p 8088 --with-threads --reload --debugger`
If I close the connection then the superset stops running.

That's why I want to create a systemd service file for Apache Superset.

Here is the part of creating the systemd in the bash script:

```
cat <<EOL | sudo tee /etc/systemd/system/superset.service
[Unit]
Description=Apache Superset service
After=network.target

[Service]
Type=simple
User=ubuntu
WorkingDirectory=/home/ubuntu
Environment="PATH=/home/ubuntu/venv/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin"
ExecStart=/home/ubuntu/venv/bin/superset run -h 0.0.0.0 -p 8088 --with-threads --reload --debugger
Restart=always

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
EOL

# Start and enable Superset service
sudo systemctl enable superset.service
sudo systemctl start superset.service
```

When I check the status of superset.service it says it is running. But when I check the ports listening, Python and Superset are not listening to 8088.
Here is the logs after running `journalctl -u superset.service`

```
-- Logs begin at Fri 2023-08-18 02:58:49 UTC, end at Fri 2023-08-18 03:12:20 UTC. --
Aug 18 03:11:25 ip-172-31-122-121 systemd[1]: Started Apache Superset service.
Aug 18 03:11:28 ip-172-31-122-121 superset[34618]: Usage: superset [OPTIONS] COMMAND [ARGS]...
Aug 18 03:11:28 ip-172-31-122-121 superset[34618]: Try 'superset --help' for help.
Aug 18 03:11:28 ip-172-31-122-121 superset[34618]: Error: Could not locate a Flask application. You did not provide the "FLASK_APP" environment variable, and a "wsgi.py" o>
Aug 18 03:11:28 ip-172-31-122-121 systemd[1]: superset.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=2/INVALIDARGUMENT
Aug 18 03:11:28 ip-172-31-122-121 systemd[1]: superset.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Aug 18 03:11:28 ip-172-31-122-121 systemd[1]: superset.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 1.
Aug 18 03:11:28 ip-172-31-122-121 systemd[1]: Stopped Apache Superset service.
Aug 18 03:11:28 ip-172-31-122-121 systemd[1]: Started Apache Superset service.
```

This code was already in the bash script `export FLASK_APP=superset`. I don't know what else I am missing or is there another way to set it up?

By the way the Ubuntu version is 20.04 on Amazon EC2 Instance.

Comment: `This code was already in the bash script` what bash script?

Comment: How do you run it from a **new** SSH session?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the `FLASK_APP` variable is only set in the script that is setting up the service file it will not be visible to the service itself.

You probably need to add it to the list of `Environment` settings in the service file.

So something like:

```
Environment="PATH=/home/ubuntu/venv/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin"
Environment="FLASK_APP=superset"
```

Alternatively you could create a wrapper script that the service file would call instead of the command you presently have, and include the `export FLASK_APP=superset` in that.

Comment: Thank you so much! It worked! I need to study and practice more on my Linux commands and scripting.